# Converting complex Sass mixin to Stylus

Tags: responsive-design, sass, stylus

I'm converting this mixin in SCSS, [working example here](http://codepen.io/MadeByMike/pen/0dbc9b82769c3e2a0cbfc3192bcaabd3)

```
@mixin fluid-type($properties, $min-vw, $max-vw, $min-value, $max-value) {
    & {
        @each $property in $properties {
            #{$property}: $min-value;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: $min-vw) {
            @each $property in $properties {
                #{$property}: calc(#{$min-value} + #{strip-unit($max-value - $min-value)} * ((100vw - #{$min-vw}) / #{strip-unit($max-vw - $min-vw)}));
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: $max-vw) {
            @each $property in $properties {
                #{$property}: $max-value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to Stylus [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ganar/pen/PNvPYg)

I found a number of problems while making the conversion:

- Automatic conversion of the code from SCSS to Stylus did not work, but I did manage to successfully convert the most important ones.
- The expressions are correct, but get rendered outside their corresponding tags, even though they are supposed to be inside each one.

The article that originated this code is **Truly Fluid Typography With vh And vw Units** in Smashing Mag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code in stylus would be more or less like this:

```
   fluid-type($properties, $min-vw, $max-vw, $min-value, $max-value)
      &
        for $property in $properties
          {$property}: $min-value
        @media screen and (min-width: $min-vw)
          for $property in $properties
            {$property}: "calc(%s + %s * ((100vw - %s) / %s))" %($min-value strip-unit($max-value - $min-value) $min-vw strip-unit($max-vw - $min-vw))
        @media screen and (min-width: $max-vw)
          for $property in $properties
            {$property}: $max-value
```

Then, to extract the number of the value you can use the unit() function:

```
strip-unit($value)
    unit($value, '')
```

The css code generated is the same as SCSS example, see in codepen:
https://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/LNwyJZ

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @blonfu: I was going nuts trying to get the `for $property in $properties` to work. I did manage to make the example work on a simplified way, but then vertical rhythm broke on the following example given in the article. 

The technique proposed by the author is very interesting, but it is better to deal with it on a new project, not in an existing one

Comment: I have converted a SASS function  to stylus. The CSS generated is identical, it is not enough?

Comment: It is perfect: the last bit is another issue regarding another example in the same article cited above. I was trying to get both vertical rhythm and proportional headings sizes to work together, but could not do it.